Using ref.read(secondProvider.notifier).performOperation() just after ref.invalidate(firstProvider) where performOperation reads firstProvider
Post adding data to my firestore database, using a
Future<void> addNewData(BuildContext context, String data) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Scaffold(
        // add data in a text field and using a button post to firestore
      );
    }
  );
}

I want to get updated FutureProvider which is defined as
@riverpod
class FetchData extends _$FetchData {
  @override
  Future<List<Data>> build() async {
    List<Data> _myList = [];
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('data')
        .get();
    for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
      _myList.add(Data.fromMap(doc));
    }
    return _myList;
  }
}

Also, a function is used to manually set a TextField's value and is notified of this change through a SecondProvider. This provider reads the state of fetchDataProvider in performOperation function.
@riverpod
class SecondProvider extends _$SecondProvider {
  @override
  String? build() {
    return '';
  }

  void performOperation(String data) {
    final AsyncValue<List<Data>> myList = ref.read(fetchDataProvider);
    String uid = '';
    if (myList.value != null && myList.hasValue) {
      int checked = 0;
      if (myList.value!.length > 0) {
        for (var item in myList.value!) {
          if (item == data) {
            uid = item;
            state = uid;
            break;
          }
          checked = checked + 1;

          /// If data did not match to any of the myList items from base then set to empty
          if (checked == myList.value!.length) {
            state = uid;
          }
        }
      } else {
        state = uid;
      }
    }
  }
}

So, in the UI code, inside a onPressed of a button, I do
addNewData(context, dataController!.text).then((_) {
  ref.invalidate(fetchDataProvider);
  ref.read(SecondProvider.notifier).performOperation(dataController!.text);
});

Since ref.invalidate takes time, ref.read after that does give wrong state of '';
Above code is simplified version, this will make more sense when Data is a class and one of its field is generated by database. That db generated field is needed in second Provider.
How to wait for fetch data provider to get updated with new value then do performOperation? or Am I doing something conceptually wrong.
Thanks

Does it work to add a await ref.read(fetchDataProvider.future); before your ref.read(SecondProvider.notifier).performOperation(dataController!.text); ?

I want to await ref.invalidate but its not allowed gives error "This expression has a type void, so its value can't be used". Also, my performOperation has a return type void, gives same error.

Yes, if they don't return futures, you cannot await for it. But adding an extra line await ref.read(fetchDataProvider.future); just after  ref.invalidate(fetchDataProvider); should do the trick. You will need to make the method inside .then async

Got it, what you mean. thanks. Acts like ref.refresh but without the need to store the returned data in local variable.

you could try to make :
 final  myList =  await ref.read(fetchDataProvider.future);

it should wait the loading of the fetchDataProvider state.

Yes, it also will work. But I have gone with the solution in the comments of the question.
